# The simplest solution for strings duplicate

Tags: c#, string, duplicates, complexity-theory

what is your simplest algorithm to find duplicate chars?

```
string a = "school";
string b = "ofrock";
```

output should be o,c (not ooc). can you find O(n) linear complexity? I can't

```
string a = "School";
string b = "ofRock";
string c = a + b;
char[] cc = c.ToCharArray();

Dictionary<char, int> d = new Dictionary<char, int>();
Dictionary<char, int> l = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (char ccc in cc)
{
    try
    {
        d.Add(ccc, 1);
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            l.Add(ccc, 1);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "find strings duplicate"?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, your code gives you what you expect.  What's your question?

Comment: I think you're looking for a list of characters which appear in a string more than once with no duplicates.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: edited duplicate chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple approach, you can use `Intersect`:

```
var result = a.Intersect(b);
```

Comment: There is no need to call `Distinct`.

Comment: I got result = null. Not working. I actually looking for an algorithm simpler than mine . O(n) complexity

Comment: @JohnRyann: I have tested on your sample, it still works from my side

Comment: yup.typo on myside. it works. but again I am looking for an algorithm